# Ошибка undefined reference при сплите класса на файлы

Tags: c++, классы, файловая-система

Возникла проблема при сплите класса на объявление в header файле, и реализацию в cpp файле:

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Test.h"

int main()
{
    Test a;

    a.Print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Test.h

```
#pragma once

class Test
{
private:
    int* data;
public:
    Test();

    ~Test();

    void Print();
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Test.h"

Test::Test(){
    int* data = new int(0);
}

Test::~Test(){
    delete data;
}

void Test::Print(){
    std::cout << *data << std::endl;
}
```

И при сборке main.cpp выдается ошибка undefined referenceу каждого метода класса.
Честно говоря не понимаю почему так происходит. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вероятно, в проект не добавлен Test.cpp?